# Get Firebase REST API streaming working

Tags: javascript, rest, firebase

I can not seem to get this working.

```
<script>
    var urlConnect = 'https://developer-api.nest.com/?auth=CREDENTIAL';
    var source = new EventSource(urlConnect);
    source.onmessage = function (event){
        console.log(event.data);
    };
</script>
```

From my understanding this should create a streaming connection to the Firebase REST API. It does not.

The [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-streaming) says:

> set the client's Accept header to "text/event-stream"

How do I do this?

Comment: When I try `new EventSource('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/')` on Chrome 43, it immediately throws "EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.". So that is in line with the Firebase docs you also quote. I doubt this can be made to work in a browser, but I'm not an expert.